# Extract Dataset and Parameter Mapping from the RDL(SSRS) file by XML XQuery

Tags: sql, xml, reporting-services, xquery

I am using the SQL SERVER 2008 R2.
I would like to extract datasets and its parameters from the RDL data which is in the XML format. We can find the xml data in the SSRS database. The table name is dbo.Catalog.

I get all the datasets for the reports, basing on below query.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition') 
--Extract all the Datasets of a report, above URI also can be http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition 
SELECT C.path                           AS REPORT_PATH,
    T2.DN.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS DataSetName
FROM   dbo.Catalog c
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), c.content)) xmlCriteria) a
    CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//DataSets/DataSet/@Name') AS T2(DN)
WHERE C.Type=2
```

Now I would like to have all the parameters for each dataset, the mapping relationship should be report--dataset--parameter. So one report may have multiple datasets, and the dataset may have multiple parameters.

I using the cursor to go through the dataset one by one to get the result, but I believe there is a simple way to get it.

my query as below

```
DECLARE @RetVal TABLE
  (
     REPORT_PATH VARCHAR(500),
     DATASETNAME VARCHAR(200)
  );

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition')
--Extract all the Datasets of a report
INSERT INTO @RetVal
SELECT C.path                           AS REPORT_PATH,
       T2.DN.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS DataSetName
FROM   dbo.Catalog c
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), c.content)) xmlCriteria) a
       CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//DataSets/DataSet/@Name') AS T2(DN)
WHERE C.Type=2 
DECLARE @REPORT_PATH VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @DataSetName VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE DataSets CURSOR FOR
  SELECT *   FROM   @RetVal

OPEN DataSets

FETCH NEXT FROM DataSets INTO @REPORT_PATH, @DataSetName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      PRINT @DataSetName;

      DECLARE @A VARCHAR(10)='';--with should start with ;

      --Extract all the parameters of the report Datasets
      WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition')
      SELECT @REPORT_PATH                     AS Report_Path,
             @DataSetName                     AS Dataset,
             T3.QP.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS Dataset_Parameter,
             T4.CT.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS Command_Text
      FROM   dbo.Catalog c
             CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), c.content)) xmlCriteria) a
             CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//DataSets/DataSet[@Name=sql:variable("@DataSetName")]/Query/QueryParameters/QueryParameter/@Name')AS T3(QP)
             CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//DataSets/DataSet[@Name=sql:variable("@DataSetName")]/Query/CommandText')AS T4(CT)
      WHERE  C.path = @REPORT_PATH

      FETCH NEXT FROM DataSets INTO @REPORT_PATH, @DataSetName
  END

CLOSE DataSets

DEALLOCATE DataSets
```

any comments ?

--- 2017-03-14 18:05:29 ---

```html
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' AS URI1,
'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' AS URI2,DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition')

      SELECT DISTINCT *FROM(
      SELECT C1.path                      AS Report_Path,
             --T2.DP.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS Description,
             T4.CT.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS CommandText,
             T5.PN.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS Dataset_Parameter,
             NULL STORED_PROCEDURE
      FROM   dbo.Catalog c1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Catalog c on c1.LinkSourceID=C.ItemID
             CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), c.content)) xmlCriteria) a
             CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//Description')AS T2(DP)
             CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//DataSets/DataSet')AS T3(QP)
             CROSS APPLY T3.QP.nodes('Query/CommandText')AS T4(CT)
             CROSS APPLY T3.QP.nodes('Query/QueryParameters/QueryParameter/@Name') AS T5(PN)
             --CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//DataSets/DataSet[@Name=''GetCompanyDetails'']/Query/QueryParameters/QueryParameter/@Name')AS T3(QP)
             --CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//DataSets/DataSet[@Name=''GetCompanyDetails'']/Query/CommandText')AS T4(CT)/Operational Reporting/Finance/
      WHERE  C1.path like '/Regional Reporting/%/Finance/%'
      UNION ALL
      SELECT C1.path                      AS Report_Path,
             --T2.DP.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS Description,
             T4.CT.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS CommandText,
             T3.QP.value('.', 'varchar(200)') AS Dataset_Parameter,
             NULL STORED_PROCEDURE
      FROM   dbo.Catalog c1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Catalog c on c1.LinkSourceID=C.ItemID
             CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(max), c.content)) xmlCriteria) a
             CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//URI2:Description')AS T2(DP)
             CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//URI2:DataSets/URI2:DataSet')AS T3(QP)
             CROSS APPLY T3.QP.nodes('URI2:Query/URI2:CommandText')AS T4(CT)
             CROSS APPLY T3.QP.nodes('URI2:Query/URI2:QueryParameters/URI2:QueryParameter/@Name') AS T5(PN)
             --CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//URI2:DataSets/URI2:DataSet[@Name=''GetCompanyDetails'']/URI2:Query/URI2:QueryParameters/URI2:QueryParameter/@Name')AS T3(QP)
             --CROSS APPLY A.xmlCriteria.nodes('//URI2:DataSets/URI2:DataSet[@Name=''GetCompanyDetails'']/URI2:Query/URI2:CommandText')AS T4(CT)
      WHERE  C1.path like '/Regional Reporting/%/Finance/%' ) A
      WHERE 1=1 and commandtext like 'global.gp_sec_pINSTANCE_COMPANIES'ORDER BY 1,2,3
      
      
      --reference http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10281/xquery-lab-2-an-example-using-outer-apply.aspx
```

Comment: yes. is it too late? :(